# Adjust vspace between multiple align environments

Tags: spacing, amsmath, align

I am using some independant align environments directly one after the other one and it produces some nasty space between them. Is there any workaround to shrink the size of the space a little bit?

**Example:**
[image: Example]

My code looks like this:

```
\newcounter{eqn}[section]
\newcommand{\eqn}{\refstepcounter{eqn}\tag{\thesection.\arabic{eqn}}}
\newcommand{\xeqn}[1]{\begin{align}\eqn #1\end{align}}
...
\xeqn{foo}
\xeqn{bar}
\xeqn{random}
```

Comment: Please post you code so we can comment on it. You are probably leaving a blank line in between the `align` environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `gather` environment:

```
\begin{gather}
\text{$x>y$ genau dann, wenn $x-y\in P$,}\\
\text{$x\ge y$ genau dann, wenn $x>y$ oder $x=y$,}\\
\text{$x<y$ genau dann, wenn $y-x\in P$,}\\
\text{$x\ge y$ genau dann, wenn $x<y$ oder $x=y$,}
\end{gather}
```

Never use two consecutive math environments.

Comment: Works, but i have "problems" with the tags/numering as i use a very weird method... can you explain me how to adjust the gather code for my needs and my posted code? - **EDIT** Inserted `\eqn` before every line and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `\eqn`, but rather follow barbara's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

@egreg's recommendations to use the `gather` environment, and never to use two consecutive math environments, are seconded.

if all (numbered) equations are to be numbered the same way as these, there's a much simpler method: put the command

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

in your preamble and forget about `\tag` and the definitions for `\eqn` and `\xeqn` which would no longer be needed.  read the manual for `amsmath` on this topic -- `texdoc amsmath` if you have a tex live installation, or follow [this link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).