# Center single line(s) in align

Tags: align

How is it able to center a single line in an `align`?

I want to center `0 = 0`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0 = 0\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50483/579) contains some possibly relevant information regarding using `aligned` together with `gather*`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm unsure what exactly you want to point out

Comment: The answers contain examples using both `gather*` and `aligned`, although only a single "column" is aligned.  This might not be an obvious help to you, but it might help some future person loolking for information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have more or less the spacing of the original code, I'd use the `alignedat` environment, to have full control on the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
0 = 0\\
\begin{alignedat}{2}
a &= b &\hspace{10em} c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible, to align the `0=0` with a more equations `-0=0`, ...?

Comment: Not sure to fully see what you want, but try nesting them  in another `aligned`    environment.

Comment: This works. Another question: Did YOU choose the space `10em` freely? AMS splits the hole free horizontal space around and in-between the equations equally, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually `&\hspace{10em}c` denotes the l.h.s. of the 2nd column of alignment. This l.h.s. is right-aligned w.r.t. the following `&=`.

Comment: I'm unsure, if I got this right. Especially I'm unsure, what l.h.s. stands for... I guess `alignedat` is just an `aligned` with zero space between the equations, right?

Comment: Or ONE `alignedat{2}` can be viewed as as TWO `aligned` side by side: `\begin{aligned}
a &= b\\
a &= b\\
a &= b\\
a &= b
\end{aligned}\hspace{10em}
\begin{aligned}
c &= d\\
c &= d\\
c &= d\\
c &= d
\end{aligned}`

Comment: Any of `align, alignat, aligned,alignedat`with 2n-1 ampersands is the juxtaposition of n alignment columns, with no space between them in the case of `alignat`  and `alignedat`. This feature gives you the possibility to control the spacing between these columns by adding some horizontal space at the end of a column or the beginning of the next one. Is it clear?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
0 = 0\\
\begin{aligned}
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d\\
a &= b & c &= d
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :-( Also I was using gathered package :-) LOL.

Comment: @Sebastiano Great minds think alike!